# android Change orientation removing button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I've set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` on an activity to stop it restarting the activity everytime the orientation changes. Now this works fine but I think it's stopping the correct layouts from being used.

E.G. I have different layout folders for different orientations and sizes of screen. So if I start the activity in `portrait`, when I change the orientation to `landscape`, it's not using my landscape layout.

Also if I start the activity in `landscape`, when I change the orientation to `portrait`, it's not using my portrait layout.

Basically what I want the app to do is not start the activity again once the orientation changes, but use the correct layout when the orientation is changed!

I was thinking I could use the `onConfigurationChanged` method to explicitly change the layout in code?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What I've ended up doing is keeping `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest file. Doing it this way stops me being able to use my correct layout folders for portrait and landscape.

To overcome this issue, I override the `onConfigurationChange` method to set the correct information I needed for the activity to run as expected once the orientation changes. below is the code I've used:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.hearing_test);
    //Any other information needed for the activity to work correctly
}
```

Thanks for the help and guidance @mihail, helped me get to the bottom of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

when you use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` this tells to Android that you will maintain these changes by yourself - this means you have to change your layout (`setContentView`) and initialize it manually (set values of controls - EditTexts, Spinners etc.)

Comment: So what do you thinks the best way to go about this, 1) use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` and `onConfigurationChanged` method to say use a particular layout? or 2) Use the `SavedInstanceState` method so I don't have to say which layout to use on orientation change?

Comment: it really depends on you. I'd follow the android workflow and use the `SavedInstanceState`

Comment: Ok, it looks like thats the way I need to do it anyway because I need the activity to use the correct layout. Because it's a test activity I'm a bit confused to what I need to save on orientation, because it's going to need to know how far through the test it is, going to look into this today, Thanks for your help mate

Answer (score -1):

That is exactly *why* the `Activity` is destroyed and recreated: to apply new resources.
Do not use `android:configChanges="orientation"` if you have different layouts for portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: I get that, but the activity is a test so I don't want it to restart the activity because it will restart the test. I'm in a bit of a pickle because I need it to restart the activity for the layout change, but I also don't want the activity to restart because the test will restart. Haven't got a clue how to go about doing it

Comment: I'm assuming we aren't talking about unit tests. You should save your progress in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState`.